# electron height changes after minimize, restore

Tags: electron

I am using electron version 8.2.5. The window height increases after minimize and restore and goes below my task bar.

```
  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: (size.width / 2) - (550 / 2),
    y: 0,
    width: 550,
    height: size.height,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false
  });
```

I googled it and found this workaround to set size on restore event:

```
  win.on('restore', () => {
    win.setSize(550, size.height);
  });
```

But when doing that the window flickers twice after minimize and restore. Is there any other way to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using workAreaSize, try to use size.

```
const electronScreen = screen;
const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().size;
```

I'm using electron 8.2.4 but works for me and I don´t have to use the event on restore.

Comment: I think you didn't check properly the issue exists for size or maybe you are using different settings. My settings are the window is frameless and non-resizeable.